# Error message "E: unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer"

Tags: wireless, kernel, dual-boot, firmware

I am using an Acer Aspire 5002WLMi laptop and set up a dual boot with Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04. Wi-Fi is working well in Windows XP, but when I start Ubuntu I will get the below error.

```
[ 95.514855] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all the instruction on this website.
```

Then I followed the instructions from the below link.

file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/MGL/Desktop/how%20to%20install%20ubuntu/Ubuntu%2012.04%20Splash%20Screen%20Lockup%20with%20LiveCD%20_%20Ben%20Rousch%27s%20Cluster%20of%20Bleep.htm

But I am stuck in installing the Broadcom Wi-Fi firmware in Terminal, and it is showing this error:

> E: unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer

How can I proceed?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: In your case you probably have the BCM4318. Please use the duplicate question marked since it solves almost all models for the Broadcom. BTW updating to 14.04 will have less issues than 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have to have an internet connection somehow.  Then you need to add the software source(repositories) needed for the b43.  Make sure that they look like the image below.  Make sure that you have a check mark just like the image.

[image]

Then To install the firmware,

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Another way is to open Synaptic and go to Settings > Repositories and enable as shown in the image above, and then search for b43 and install your packages.

All that of course after adding the software source(repositories)

Note: If you don't have Synaptic Package Manager installed, you can do so by clicking below.

[image]

Comment: @PeterMortensen  What Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: Its perhaps very useful if you explain in your answer why the OP should do this, what they should expect to happen, how to revert etc.